# Swift Get PKToolPicker Position

Tags: ios, swift, apple-pencil, pktoolpicker

I am using the PKToolPicker with PKCanvasView. I would like to add some buttons directly above the tool picker UI on iPhone.
I am currently using the code below to try to get the frame position of the tool picker:

```
let toolBarPos = toolPicker.frameObscured(in: view)
print("View covered by tool picker: \(toolBarPos)")
```

but it returns the following:

`View covered by tool picker: (inf, inf, 0.0, 0.0)`

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the tool picker is actually obscuring any part of `view` at all?

Comment: It is obscuring part of the main view, however it is actually added to the Canvas view, but this produces the same log.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you wait until the toolPicker is done animating before you get toolPicker.frameObscured(in: view)